# Using jQuery to Generate a Grid of DIVs, but Get Wierd Behavior if it Isn't 10 x 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery to generate a grid of divs that I will then style to become the board of a game. It works fine when I set the grid to 10 x 10, but when I increase the number of squares, even by one, the second column from the left either doesn't display at all (although the html is fine), or it extends from the bottom of the grid down instead of up.

I've tried messing with the stylesheet and pretty much every variable in the code to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var row_count = 11;

  var base = document.getElementById('base');

  var square = '<div class="square"></div>';

  var col_count = 11; // Sets the number of columns

  while (col_count >= 0) { //Outer loops controls the columns.
    row_count = 11; // sets the number of rows

    while (row_count >= 0) {
      $('<div class="square" id = "in_col' + '_' + col_count + '_' + row_count + '"></div>', {
        "class": "square"
      }).appendTo('#base');

      row_count--;
    }

    col_count--;
  }

  // These two values, for posx and posy are the positioning 
  // coordinates for the squares of the grid
  var posx = 10;
  var posy = 10;

  var col = 0; // Initiates the column counter for the below while loop

  while (col <= 11) { // must match var col_count above
    $.each($('div[id^="in_col_' + col + '"]'), function() {

      $(this).css('top', posy);
      $(this).css('left', posx);

      posy += 41;

    });

    posy = 10;
    posx += 41;

    col++;
  }
});
```

```css
.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='base'>

</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptwickler/Lc0rbcae/1/) of example

Comment: [Fiddle with problem code](https://jsfiddle.net/xc9gyv8p/)

Comment: Just added fiddle into the post. Sorry for the oversight.

Comment: Your loop is setting the wrong "top" values for the cells in that second column, probably due a logic error in re-initializing the values.  I'd concentrate on that, not the css.

Comment: Dave, that's what I thought initially, but why, then does it work in every other column? Why does it work when I have a 10 x 10 grid?

Comment: @ptwickler it works because your ID does not repeat itself. The minute you get above 10 you have `in_col_1` and `in_col_10` which both work for `$('div[id^="in_col_' + col + '"]')` this selector when col is equal to 10. https://jsfiddle.net/Lc0rbcae/2/

Comment: Also as a personal gripe the issue with almost all the answers below is no one except one or two people showed what the issue was. They just rewrote the code to work in another way. So annoying. Is there better ways to write this code. Yes. But the poster didn't ask how to write it better. They asked why it didn't do what they expected. It aggravates me when people don't answer the question. Its so easy to completely rewrite code to work in a different way. Solving whats wrong with the code and then showing a better way is what SO should be about.

Answer (score 2):

I refactored the code a bit, using for loops instead so we don't have to keep track of iteration variables.  I also used `float: left;` on the tiles and `clear: both;` whenever we want to wrap down to a new line.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var col_count = 11; //Sets the number of columns
    var row_count = 11; //sets the number of rows
    var base = $('#base');
    var square = '<div class="square"></div>';

    for(var i = 0; i < col_count; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < row_count; j++){
        var tile = $(square);
        if(j === 0) tile.addClass('newRow');
        base.append(tile);
      }
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.square {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.newRow {
    clear: both;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0g6y9th/

Comment: Your solution works fine. I just made a slight adjustment to the css so that the borders don't appear doubled up.

https://jsfiddle.net/e0g6y9th/

Comment: Sweet that is a nice addition, thanks.  I'll link that fiddle instead.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in `$.each($('div[id^="in_col_' + col + '"]'), function() {`
col_10 is called 2 times. Change it to  `$.each($('div[id^="in_col_' + col + '_"]'), function() {`, a more restrictive regex

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var row_count = 11;

  var base = document.getElementById('base');

  var square = '<div class="square"></div>';

  var col_count = 11; // Sets the number of columns

  while (col_count >= 0) { //Outer loops controls the columns.
    row_count = 11; // sets the number of rows

    while (row_count >= 0) {
      $('<div class="square" id = "in_col' + '_' + col_count + '_' + row_count + '"></div>', {
        "class": "square"
      }).appendTo('#base');

      row_count--;
    }

    col_count--;
  }

  // These two values, for posx and posy are the positioning 
  // coordinates for the squares of the grid
  var posx = 10;
  var posy = 10;

  var col = 0; // Initiates the column counter for the below while loop

  while (col <= 11) { // must match var col_count above
    $.each($('div[id^="in_col_' + col + '_"]'), function() {

      $(this).css('top', posy);
      $(this).css('left', posx);

      posy += 41;

    });

    posy = 10;
    posx += 41;

    col++;
  }
});
```

```css
.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='base'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours is more a mathematical problem. My version is much easier to understand, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xc9gyv8p/1/).

go row by row and column by column in each row. so `var i` is each row and `var j` is each column in the row (starting every time by `1` and count up till reach `var col_count`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var row_count = 11;
  var col_count = 11;
  var size = 41;

  var base = document.getElementById('base');

  for (var i=1; i<=row_count; i++) {
        for (var j=1; j<=col_count; j++) {
        $('<div class="square" id = "in_col' + '_' + j + '_' + i + '"></div>')
            .addClass('square')
          .css({
            'left': j*size,
            'top': i*size
          })
          .appendTo('#base');
      }
  }
});
```

to select each elements in column 1 use `div[id^="in_col_1_"]`. I would recommend you to work with [data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) attributes by changing the code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var row_count = 11;
  var col_count = 11;
  var size = 41;

  var base = document.getElementById('base');

  for (var i=1; i<=row_count; i++) {
        for (var j=1; j<=col_count; j++) {
        $('<div class="square" id = "in_col' + '_' + j + '_' + i + '"></div>')
            .addClass('square')
            .attr('data-col', j)
            .attr('data-row', i)
            .css({
                'left': j*size,
                'top': i*size
            })
            .appendTo('#base');
      }
  }
});
```

so you can easily select elements in row 1 by `div[data-row="1"]` and column 1 by `div[data-col="1"]`. Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xc9gyv8p/5/).

Comment: He might still need to find just a certain row or column later, though.

Comment: he can find out each row or column by combing i and j. Row 3 Col 4 is i==3 and j==4 or every 3rd column is only j==3 or the whole 4th row is i==4 and so on.. wheres the problem? and also he can use the id identifier, which is the same as his before.

Comment: The problem is that $('div[id^="in_col_1"]') will still match multiple columns.

Comment: $('div[id^="in_col_1_"]') not.

Comment: it is only about how he is using the code, he also can work with $('div[data-col="1"]') if he adds the j to each element by .attr('data-col', j);

Answer (score 0):

The selector in your $.each loop is matching columns multiple times.  A simple solution will be to zero-pad the numbers in your ids:

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

Then change

```
$('<div class="square" id = "in_col' + '_' + col_count + '_' + row_count + '"></div>', {
        "class": "square"
      }).appendTo('#base');
```

To

```
  $('<div class="square" id = "in_col' + '_' + pad(col_count,3) + '_' + pad(row_count,3) + '"></div>', {
    "class": "square"
  }).appendTo('#base');
```

And

```
$.each($('div[id^="in_col_' + col + '"]'), function() {
```

to

```
$.each($('div[id^="in_col_' + pad(col,3) + '"]'), function() {
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xc9gyv8p/4/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xc9gyv8p/3/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var row_count = 11;
  var col_count = 11;
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var offX = 41;
  var offY = 41;
  for(var i = 0; i < col_count; i++){
    $('#base').append('<div id="col_'+i+'" class="col" style="left:'+x+'px"><div>');
    x += offX;
    y = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < row_count; j++){
        $('#col_'+i).append('<div class="square" id="row_'+j+'" style="top:'+y+'px"></div>');
      y += offY;
    }  
  }
 });
.col{
  position: absolute;
}
.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

insted for running while loop backward run it forward, it will fix your problem

```
var row_count = 0;
var col_count = 0; // Sets the number of columns

while (col_count <= 10){ //Outer loops controls the columns.
   row_count = 0; // sets the number of rows

    while (row_count <= 10) { // Inner loop controls the cells in each column.
        $('<div class="square" id = "in_col' + '_' + col_count + '_' + row_count +'"></div>', {"class":"square"}).appendTo('#base');

        row_count++;
    }

    col_count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IrkenInvader, thanks, I went with your solution, much cleaner than what I had originally and obviates the need for the bit of code (the regex in the jQuery selector) that was causing the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var col_count = 11;// Sets the number of columns
var row_count = 11; //sets the number of rows
var base = $('#base');

for(var i = 0; i < col_count; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < row_count; j++) {

        var square = '<div class="square" id = "in_col' + '_' + j + '_' + i +'"></div>';
        var tile = $(square);
        if (j === 0) tile.addClass('newRow');
        base.append(tile);
    }

}

});
```